# Abstract-only European conferences in OR with economics sections

Tags: academia

Do you know some **European conferences** requiring to send **sole abstract** which is then published in **book of abstracts**? I am searching mostly for conferences in **Operations Research with an economics section** (but other related sciences could also be ok if they meet the conditions).

Do you know some of these conferences, for example like **EURO conference** which suits it the best: https://euro2022espoo.com/?

I know there is a list on a site such as **INOMICS**: https://inomics.com/, but I haven't seen there any operations research conferences as EURO.

Do you know some other lists/sites?

Possibly, conferences requiring to send a paper but publishing only abstracts in book of abstracts would be ok as well, but they are not the prime focus of this question.